# Observer pattern: notify with state

Tags: java, design-patterns, observer-pattern

The examples I've seen on the internet only give `notifyObservers()` method to the Observable object. What if I want to also pass some data to the observers, so that they know if they should react to it or not? Does the observer pattern allow passing the data like maybe:

`notifyObservers(Event e)`.

Or maybe the observers themselves should pull the change? Like maybe:
`notifyObservers() -> call observer.update()`

and then each observer decides if the new data is relevant for them, `observable.getData()`. However with this approach, it is unclear to me, how to get only the data that has changes, if it's at all needed.

**Edit, example:**

Say I want to make a taxi firm with operators, clients and taxi. As per *@Pritam Banerjee's* answer, I will say that taxi firm is a mediator between operators and clients (e.g. why - client can call for a taxi by phone, or online). Then my operators are subjects, and taxis are observers.

`Operator ---observes---> TaxiFirm`

`TaxiFirm(waits for client) ---notifies one---> Operator` (firm selects which operator is responsible, and passes a client to operator)

`Taxi ---observes all---> Operators` (need to somehow push data here, if the taxi is occupied, it can't accept new client)

`Taxi ---notifies---> Operator` (if taxi can accept a client it will notify operator about it, I am not concerned about any race conditions, because this event will be triggered manually. Also, maybe Taxi should notify the Firm and not operator?)

I think it's possible that TaxiFirm doesn't need to pass client to operator, but thinking about real life, it's really operators who speak to clients...

I've written down my thought process, please help me with figuring out the architecture for this model.

Comment: I think you have to redefine your flow with concern of Java implementation. Your first 2 lines are ok. The firm should select an unoccupied taxi for an unoccupied operator and notify him(operator) with the client and taxi info. :))

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the ObserverPattern allows you to pass information through its `notify` method. If a taxi needs the client info you can just pass:

```
observer.notify(ClientInfo info)
```

And of course the Observers could, instead, request the info:

```
observer.notify()

void notify() {
    update();
}
```

Both are possible, but then, I would NOT say you really have the ObserverPattern here. According to this pattern, the Subject simply notifies **all** Observers. But what you described is that the Subject should notify one of the taxis, wait for its response (if the taxi is already carrying a passenger), and then possibly notify the next taxi. You could call that a variation of the ObserverPattern, but it's different.

A simple suggestion, for you to get started:

**class Operator:**

```
List<Taxi> taxis;

boolean chooseTaxi(RideNumber rideNumber) {
    for (Taxi taxi : taxis) {
        boolean isAccepted = taxi.notify(this, rideNumber);
        if (isAccepted) {
           markTaxiRideAsAccepted(taxi, rideNumber);
           return true;
        }
    }
    return false; // No taxi accepted the ride.
}
```

**class Taxi:**

```
boolean notify(Operator operator, RideNumber rideNumber) {
    if (isTaxiAlreadyCarryingPassenger()) return false;

    ClientInfo clientInfo = operator.getClientInfo(this, rideNumber);
    startClientProcess(clientInfo);

    return true;
}
```

Note: The `RideNumber` is just an identification number that the taxi later uses to request the client info from the operator. You could instead send the `clientInfo` through the notify method, but then all taxis would get this info, which is terrible for security, and could also be confusing (sending information which should not be used).

---

**Update:**

If this is a homework assignment, and you must use the exact ObserverPattern, you can do this:

**class Operator:**

```
List<Taxi> taxis;

void notifyAllTaxis(RideNumber rideNumber) {
    for (Taxi taxi : taxis) {
        taxi.notify(this, rideNumber);            
        }
    }        
}

ClientInfo getClientInfo(this, rideNumber) {
    if (isRideNotYetAccepted(rideNumber)) {
        markRideAsAccepted(taxi, rideNumber);
        return getClientInfo(rideNumber);
    }
    else return null;
}
```

**class Taxi:**

```
void notify(Operator operator, RideNumber rideNumber) {
    if (!isTaxiAlreadyCarryingPassenger()) {

        ClientInfo clientInfo = operator.getClientInfo(this, rideNumber);
        if (clientInfo != null) startClientProcess(clientInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. The example that you gave me is not technically observer pattern is it? As you said, it should notify all of the observers, and here Operator notifies taxis one by one as long as it doesn't find a free taxi. I can't say that it suits me well, as I specifically need to use the Observer pattern. Maybe another way to do this would be: Taxis observe Operators, operator notifies all of the taxis about the client, all free taxis notify the operators that they can accept the client, operator picks one taxi, and links it with client...

Comment: When I write this, it seems like it calls for some different pattern altogether, or maybe some two-way observation. Not sure if pure observer can be user in this context now.

Comment: I am not sure where I can use the real observer pattern in this context. Of all the entities, really only first which matches some condition needs to be notified...

Comment: Well, it's a semantics issue. It's a VARIATION of the ObserverPattern, yes, in the sense that the taxis will register with the Operator and get notified, but not the textbook definition, as I explained. Why are you so concerned with using the textbook definition of the ObserverPattern? Is this a homework assignment where you where asked to use it? If so, keep in mind that, as programmer, you should stick to the best way of implementing the code. The way I explained is efficient and clear, so don't create a contrived way of using a textbook definition of a pattern just for the sake of it.

Comment: @VincasStonys please see my updated answer using the exact ObserverPattern.

Comment: I perfectly understand what you're getting at, but yes, this is an assignment, and I need to use the exact pattern, that's why I'm trying to restructure the program in a way that it fits, even though much better way to do that is obviously what you wrote. I'm in the progress of thinking off another domain in which to use observer pattern (along with many others...) where it actually fits, both the textbook definition and the actual need for it, as it currently allows for nitpicking (either it wont fit the definition or it will be used in a vacuous way). But yes, your answer is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Observer Design Pattern** with **Mediator Pattern** so that the application can also subscribe and publish data to the other related applications.

For an example of this you can look over [here](http://www.journaldev.com/1739/observer-design-pattern-in-java).

For more details on **Mediator Design Patterns** you can read this [article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mediator_pattern.htm).

Comment: I have check out the example, but I'm still not entirely sure, how it fits together with observer pattern. It seems that it's a way to encapsulate references between communicating objects. I will edit the question with some more specific example.